# iOS and PHP password has and salt

Tags: php, ios, hash, salt

I am developing an app for iOS which uses PHP as the end back. Am I better hashing and salting the password in PHP ?

If thats the case would I via https pass the password over the web server.

Regards
Kal.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read about [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question. With high quality questions you will receive better answers faster. Thanks!

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: That's the usual way, sending the plaintext password via HTTPS/SSL to the server, then the server calculates and stores a hash of the password. As already mentioned, PHP offers the function [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).